# How to know the different types of 'PLKExitStatus' enum in objective C or any enum via Xcode or in general?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, ionic-native

I have a variable `status` with type `PLKExitStatus` which is an enum.I want to know all possible types of this enum so that to perform operations based on what exact type is being returned.
For example, PLKExitStatus*type1* , PLKExitStatus*type2* etc. (i am guessing the types here)

When i try to print object in xcode, i am just seeing the type being returned.

[image]

Comment: Objective C inherits its enums from C. They're just integers. To make any sense of them, you have to break them apart into the constituent constants that we ORed together to build up the value in the first place. So you can check `status & PLKExitStatustype1`, `status & PLKExitStatustype2`, etc. So for finding out what those constants are: you can jump to definition on `PLKExitStatus`, and you should be able to see all the constants declared in roughly the same place.